# Engine temperature rising

Tags: cooling

Most recently I have noticed my temperature gauge rising and im hearing bubbling in the overflow jug. I opened the hood and took off the radiator cap and all the fluid was it drained from the radiator but then it started filling back up.

I am wondering if it is my head gasket or my water pump.

I drove it this morning to work and when I got to work I opened the hood and the radiator was warm to the touch but there was no fluid on the ground. the overflow was about 1/2 full. so can you tell him if it is the water pump or the head gasket. It is not blowing smoke. I do let it warm up before taking off in the cold weather.

It is a 2002 Buick Lesabre 6 cylinder.

Could it be the blower motor for the cooling system

Answer (score 1):

What you can check or replace, You have 2 cooling fans, each has a fuse and relay, check fuses first, if fuses are good then replace both relays. Cooling System must be full for these to operate properly. Fuses and relays are in the under hood fuse box.

With the engine cold fill the radiator with coolant to the top. Do this first.

You may have a coolant leak also. This should be diagnosed and repaired first. this model of car is prone to a coolant leak into the plastic intake manifold because the erg tube in the intake eventually melts the seal around it which contains coolant and is sucked into the intake and is burned in the combustion chambers leaving no signs of coolant on the ground when you park it.

[image]

Relays are 37 (low) 40 (high)

Fuses are 46 (fan 1) and 47 (fan 2)

Relays are controlled by the Powertrain Control Module

[image]

Comment: Oh, I had the same problem. Moab, thank you for information. I was eager to find it out for a long time.